# natbib and \citet: inserting `and' after the last semicolon

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, multiple-citations

Using `natbib` (I'm aware of `biblatex`), I'd like to replace the semicolon with the word "and" in a list of two authors and insert the word "and" after the last semicolon in a list of three or more authors.  How do I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{foo,
author={Foo},
year={2016},
Title={Foo foo}
}
@article{bar,
author={Bar},
year={2014},
Title={Bar bar}
}
@article{tilde,
author={Tilde},
year={2015},
Title={Tilde tilde}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\begin{document}

\citet{foo,bar,tilde} are nuts.  \citet{foo,bar} are in fact insane.

\bibliography{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my experience, it's simply not a good idea to list multiple bib entries in the argument of a single `\citet` instruction. (However, it's sort of OK to do so with `\citep`.) Instead of `\citet{foo,bar,tilde}`, just write `\citet{foo}, \citet{bar} and \citet{tilde}` and you'll be doing just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, but that wasn't the question.  I'll take a solution that solves the problem for `\citep` instead.  ;-)

Comment: The code in my answer seems to work with my extremely minimal testing, but Mico's proposed method of just writing what you want it to look like is definitely a better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, this isn't configurable using `natbib`. That said, it's not too hard to patch `natbib`'s macros to do what you want. **Keep in mind, this is just a hack.**

Insert this code in the preamble.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcount\NAT@inline@cnt
\preto\NAT@reset@citea{%
    \NAT@inline@cnt=\@ne
    \mathchardef\NAT@total@cnt=\count@
}
\def\NAT@separator{%
    \advance\NAT@inline@cnt\@ne
    \ifnum\NAT@inline@cnt=\NAT@total@cnt
        \ifnum\NAT@inline@cnt=\tw@\else
            \NAT@sep\NAT@penalty
        \fi
        \NAT@space and%
    \else
        \NAT@sep\NAT@penalty
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

**Explanation:** The user-facing `\cite` commands expand to `\NAT@citexnum` whose definition starts with the following.

```
\def\NAT@citexnum[#1][#2]#3{%
  \NAT@reset@parser
  \NAT@sort@cites{#3}%
  \NAT@reset@citea
```

As a side effect of `\NAT@sort@cites`, the total number of citations in this particular call to `\cite` is in `\count@`. The first part of my code allocates a new count register `\NAT@inline@cnt` and prepends code to `\NAT@reset@citea` set `\NAT@inline@cnt` to 1 and define `\NAT@total@cnt` to be `\count@`.

When the inline citations to a list of citations typeset, `natbib` inserts `\NAT@separator` which is normally defined to `\NAT@sep\NAT@penalty`. The rest of my code redefines this to increment our new counter and insert

- `and` if there are only two inline citations;
- `; and` if there are more than two citations and this is between the final two;
- `;` otherwise.

This works with `natbib` version 8.31b (2010/09/13), but may break completely or in subtle ways with earlier or later versions.

Comment: Hacks are good: works for me.